# Python splitting text between every instance of two specific strings (Regex)

Tags: python, regex, split, screen-scraping

I'm trying to do some kind of web scraping with python and I'm having some trouble. I have a big mass of scraped text and I'm trying to generate a list that contains every instance between two specific strings.

A bunch of lines contain something in the format of "href=*/profile/pc/WORD/matches" and I want to create a list of all the WORDs (Every word between an instance of "*/profile/pc/" and "/matches").

I tried starting with something like this but I'm not even getting any output. Any help on where to go from here?

```
import re
url="http:examplewebsite.com"  
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
web_byte = urlopen(req).read()   
webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')  
q = webpage.replace('"','_')    #Replace quotation marks with underscores
print (re.split(r'href=_/profile/pc/', q))
```

P.S. Previously I did something like this but I was only getting the first result.

```
 substring1 = '<a href=_/profile/pc/'   #Starting string before name
 substring2 = '/matches_>'   #Ending string after name
 my_string = q[(q.index(substring1)+len(substring1)):q.index(substring2)]
```

Comment: Can you eleaborate on what is  _list of all the WORDs_?

Comment: So for example, this is part of the block:


<a href=_/profile/pc/Steven/matches_>Steven</a> </div>  </div>  <div style=_display: inline-block; width: calc(50% - 5px); padding-left: 5px; overflow: hidden_>  <div class=_team_> <img src=_/assets/img/champions/achilles.jpg_> <a href=_/profile/pc/Slaet/matches_>Slaet</a> </div>  <div class=_team_> <img src=_/assets/img/champions/hou-yi.jpg_>

From this I would like to get out just the strings Steven and Slaet. You can see how each word appears in the format "profile/pc/WORD/matches".

Comment: Understood. Working on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry if I didn't explain it properly. Everything I know about coding is pulled from stack exchange and vague recollections from a single college course.

Answer (score 0):

You have many lines in `webpage` and you need to move through them all to try to match on them.

```
import re
url="http:examplewebsite.com"  
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
web_byte = urlopen(req).read()   
webpage = web_byte.decode('utf-8')  
q = webpage.replace('"','_')    #Replace quotation marks with underscores
for row in q:
    print (re.split(r'href=_/profile/pc/', row))
```

Comment: Will this work even if they aren't a bunch of lines but are instead one big mass of text? When I ran it I got something like:


[';']
['c']
['g']
['=']
['0']
['&']
['a']
['m']
['p']
[';']
['c']
['c']
['=']
['1']
['&']
['a']
['m']
['p']
[';']
['t']
['s']
['=']
['n']
['o']
['s']
['c']